# Converting Julian Date to Gregorian Date - C programming

Tags: c

I'm stuck on an assignment for C where I have to convert a Julian Date that is input by the user and convert it to Gregorian. When I run it and I enter a number for the Julian date all it prints out is 1, 0, -12 for the month, day and year. How to fix? I also don't completely understand pointers so maybe that is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void getDateFromJulian(double jd, int *month, int *day, int *year);
double getDoubleFromUser(char* msg);

int main() {
    double jd = 0;
    int month, day, year;

    jd = getDoubleFromUser("Enter a valid Julian Day: ");

    if (jd != -999.0) {
        getDateFromJulian(jd, &month, &day, &year);

        printf("Month, day, year is: %d, %d, %d \n", month, day, year);
    }

    return;
}

double getDoubleFromUser(char* msg){
    int input;
    int term;

    //check for valid number
    printf("Enter Julian Day: \n");
    scanf_s("%1f%c");
    if (scanf_s("%1f%c", &input, &term) != 2) {
        if (term >= 0 * 41 && term <= 0 * (int)7) {
            printf("That's not a valid number!\n");
            return -999.0;
        }
    }
}

void getDateFromJulian(double jd, int *month, int *day, int *year) {
    int A, B, C, D, E, alpha;
    double Z, F;
    int JD = 0;

    F = modf(JD, &Z);

    if (Z < 2299161) {
        A = Z;
    }

    if (Z >= 2299161) {
        alpha = (int)((Z - 1867216.25) / 36524.25);
        A = Z + 1 + alpha - (int)(alpha / 4);
    }
    B = A + 1524;
    C = (int)((B - 122.1) / 365.25);
    D = (int)(365.25 * C);
    E = (int)((B - D) / 30.6001);

    day = B - D - (int)(30.6001 * E) + 0.5;

    if (E < 14) {
        month = E - 1;
    }
    if (E = 14 || 15) {
        month = E - 13;
    }

    if (month > 2) {
        year = C - 4716;
    }
    if (month = 1 || 2) {
        year = C - 5715;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: The compiler should be shrieking about assigning numbers to pointers in the function. Pay attention to your compiler; it knows more about C than you do. It is right!

Comment: The code has so many problems. Get help from compiler to beat some warnings/errors off - and then come back with the code.

Comment: Write a little bit of code. Test it. Debug it. Repeat.

Comment: @Jones: Please don't edit the code after the fact. It invalidates any answers that have been posted, and confuses future visitors.

Comment: @Mark Benningfield: I did not completely change it. I just fixed it the way the comments have asked and showed.

Comment: @Jones: You changed the pointer assignments that were one of the major problems with the code. This makes the comments and answers nonsense to someone who reads the question afterwards.

Comment: @Mark Benningfield: I apologize.

Comment: `"%1f%c"` --> sure you want a `1` there and not an `l`?

Comment: `scanf_s("%1f%c", &input, &term)` is missing an argument.  Review `scanf_s()` for details.

Comment: @chux - I need a new font, the *one* and *ell* still look virtually identical -- but yes, that should definitely be an *ell* (good eyes...).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [I need a new font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634737/converting-julian-date-to-gregorian-date-c-programming?noredirect=1#comment84270267_48634737) --> I feel [a song coming on](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/weirdalyankovic/iwantanewduck.html)

Comment: @chux - Didn't *Huey Lewis and the News* already do that one?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to the day, month, or year you should do it as follows:

```
           day[0] = B - D - (int)(30.6001 * E) + 0.5;

           month[0] = E - 1;
```

and so on. Basically, you have to assign to the first element of the pointer (array) which is sometimes a little bit clearer than using an asterisk, which you left out.

The program effectively wasn't doing anything because the output values were essentially set to gibberish.

Comment: Well, that's an interesting way of doing it.  It works.  It would be more usual to use `*day` or `*month`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to assigning integers to pointers (`month = newVal;` for example), some of your conditional tests are always true.

```
     if (E = 14 || 15) {
         month = newVal;
         newVal = E - 13;
     }
```

This assigns the value of `14 || 15` (which is `1`) to `E`, and then tests that E is non-zero, which of course, it always is.

This test (and the other one like it) should be:

```
if (E == 14 || E == 15) {
    *month = newVal;
    newVal = E - 13;
}
```

Note that the `newVal` integer is assigned to the integer that is pointed to by `month` (by using `*month`), and not the actual pointer variable `month`. This remedy should be applied to assignments to the `day` and `year` pointers also.